# Will an uncaught Exception in an AsyncTask crash an app?

Tags: android

If an `Exception` occurs in an `AsyncTask` and is not caught, will it crash the whole app? If it will not crash the app, why is that?

Is there any difference between an uncaught exception in the `doInBackground()` method and other methods such as `onPostExecute()`, `onPreExecute()`, etc?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? `AsyncTask` is just an advanced `Thread`. If there is an uncaught exception then yes the app will crash.

Comment: Yes, your app will crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way for handling uncaught `Exceptions` in your application.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file).

If you are not handling your `Exception`, it will crash your app, as expected, wherever the `Exception` is being thrown.