# IOException: No Such File or Directory (Android)

Tags: android, android-file

This is my first Android app and my first attempt at writing something to file. I'm trying to capture a log [according to these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19968400/3165621) and I'm getting the `FileNotFoundExeption ENOENT (No such file or directory)`. That's fair enough because the directory does not exist. But then how do I create the directory? Or use another one? I don't know best practices for where to write logs to email them, nor do I know how to make a new directory for them.

This is the path I'm trying to use.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "MyFirstApp/";
      String fullName = path + "mylog";
File file = new File (fullName);
```

Comment: Do you own the permission to write on the SD card?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The parent dir doesn't exist yet, you must create the parent first before creating the file

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "MyFirstApp/";
// Create the parent path
File dir = new File(path);
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}

String fullName = path + "mylog";
File file = new File (fullName);
```

Edit:

Thanks to Jonathans answer, this code sample is more correct. It uses the exists() method.

You also need the permission in your manifest:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add to Francesco's answer, that instead of asking if it's a directory, you could ask if it exists with dir.exists() method.

And also check that you've set the proper permissions in the Manifest file.

Hope it helps

Jonatan