# How to force android application to print stack trace of uncaught exception?

Tags: android, exception

when my app crashes it throws some lines in Logcat:

```
07-10 10:35:34.671  32391-32391/com.noframe.farmisagronom D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-10 10:35:34.671  32391-32391/com.noframe.farmisagronom W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415bf8b0)
```

How to force app to print stack trace of exception?

my application class code:

```
public class Application extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        try {
            super.attachBaseContext(base);
            MultiDex.install(this);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        try {
            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                    Log.e("Uncaught Exception detected in thread {}", t.getName(), e);
                }
            });
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Could not set the Default Uncaught Exception Handler", "" ,e);
        }
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Note that `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` is my try to get stack trace form exception, but it dose not work.

When i go wild with try-catch every where, i catch those exceptions. But that's not always an option, and requires a huge amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the overrides of all the log  methods [Here's the link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) with (String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) signatures.

Passing an exception as the third parameter should give you the full stacktrace in logcat.

The three-argument log methods use the **getStackTraceString()** method

Comment: you can also look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#getStackTraceString%28java.lang.Throwable%29) and here's you can also see the solution [Need to handle uncaught exception and send log file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file)

Comment: public static String getStackTraceString (Throwable tr)  i assume? And i get  that Throwable with voodoo magic  or some special  dance of uncaught exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I did this way:

```
StackTraceElement[] st = new StackTraceElement[12];
st = ex.getStackTrace();
for (StackTraceElement el: st)
    com.example.android.common.logger.Log.e(TAG, " " + el);
```

Hope it will help.