# Android Logback - Store stack trace to the log file on application crash

Tags: android, logging, crash, logback, acra

I am using [LogBack for Android](http://tony19.github.io/logback-android/) to log into a file on the public external storage of the device.

When my application crashes, I want the log file to contain the Exception and the stack trace.

How do I configure this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take a look at the following thread, I think that's exactly what you need: [Need to handle uncaught exception and send log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file)

Comment: Perfect. I will be using a handler like this: `private void handleUncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) { LOG.error("Application crashed with the following exception.", e); System.exit(1); }`