# Handling caught exception globally in Android

Tags: android, exception

I am trying to implement a crash log reporting library in Android like **Crashlytics**, **ACRA**. At the preliminary phase, I was able to get **Uncaught Exception** log using `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` which is working fine.

For handling **Caught Exceptions**, One of the above mentioned two libraries use a single line at every catch block which can be painful for a large project. Is there any way to get the log of caught exception like the uncaught one in a single place?

P.S. I also used both libraries and they are really good crash reporting mechanisms. My point was not to criticize those rather finding a better way if possible. Thanks.

Comment: please refer to this thread.
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file)

Comment: thanks for your effort. I have tried it and it is for handling uncaught exception.

Comment: If I understand your question, then no, you can't log caught exceptions without saying so in catch block

Comment: thanks for your information :)

Comment: I do not know who down voted this and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an exception occurs, it searches for a handler. If it finds one, the exception is handled and the normal control flow of the code coutinues.

So there are no clues that an exception has been caught except if specified in the corresponding catch block that actually got the exception.

Without additional logic in those catch blocks I`m afraid you could not know if an exception has ever been handled.