# Service default exception handler not working (threadID changed)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, exception

I want the user to be able to send an error report when my service crashes. I have an GUI app which gets updated using broadcasts from the service. The service runs in a different process and runs as foreground. I used the same code to attach the default exception handler to my GUI and there it works fine (opens the e-mail send app and the body of the e-mail contains the exception). But for my service threads, I cannot get them to call the UncaughtExceptionHandler.

The research I did so far is that the thread that crashes has a different threadid (12) than the thread I registered the cutom exceptionhandler on (229) The registration and the crash are in the same Timer_Tick runnable and should have the same threadid.

Logcat output:

```
> D/Registratie: General exception handler set for threadid=229 
> D/Registratie: ThreadName in Timer_Tick: Timer-0 threadId=229
> D/Registratie: ThreadName in Timer_Tick: Timer-0 threadId=229
> D/Registratie: ThreadName in Timer_Tick: Timer-0 threadId=229
> D/Registratie: Throw ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception W/dalvikvm:
> threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4169fba8)
```

Service member and method:

```
// declared non-anonymous to prevent the garbage collector erroneously clearing
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mUEHandler; 


public void attachGeneralExceptionHandler(){

        mUEHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Custom crash handler: build crashrapport and intent");
                sendExceptionReport(t,e);

                mUEHandler.uncaughtException(t, e);

            }
        };

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(mUEHandler);
        Log.d(TAG, "General exception handler set for ThreadName: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " threadid=" + Thread.currentThread().getId());

    }
```

TimerTick from the service:

```
private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if(!uncaughtExceptionHandlerSet) {
                // Make sure the exception handler is connected to this Timer_Tick thread
                attachGeneralExceptionHandler();
                uncaughtExceptionHandlerSet=true;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "ThreadName in Timer_Tick: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName()+" threadId="+Thread.currentThread().getId());

            if(testExceptionHandling){
                Log.d("TAG", "Throw ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception");
                int[] exceptionTest = new int[3];
                exceptionTest[3] = -1; // throws exception on thread with threadid 12, only one line in logcat

            }
}
```

Comment: just call `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` inside `Application#onCreate`, (you need to extend `Application` class)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) for `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` indicates:

> This handler is invoked in case **any** Thread dies due to an
>   unhandled exception

You don't need to call that method for each thread.  Try setting the default handle in the `onCreate()` method of your service.

Comment: Yes, that is what I had in the first try. That doesn't work either. I figured that it didn't work because the onCreate might be an OS thread (I could not find in the documentation what thread invokes the onCreate method).

Comment: Hmmm.  I'll research more. I thought "any" meant every thread in the process.

Comment: Yes, I think your interpretation of the documentation is right. It doesn't help my problem though. The weird thing is that I don't get a stack dump in the logcat anymore.

Comment: I'm wondering about this statement `mUEHandler.uncaughtException(t, e);` in `mUEHandler`.  Isn't that recursive?  Was your intention to propagate the exception to the previous default handler?

Comment: FWIW--For one of my apps, I implemented a default handler in an Application subclass similar to what is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file). I just tested and confirmed that this approach catches exceptions in worker threads in a service, both when the app is a single process and when the service  is in a separate process.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along qbix! The calling of uncaughtException was indeed meant to propagate the exception to the previous default handler (found it somewhere). When I remove that statement there is no change of behavior (as expected since the crash-report e-mail isn't build either). I'll take a thorough look at your solution.