# Exit app from application class

Tags: android, exception

I have a class A which extends Application.In A i am handling uncaughtexceptions. Now the issue is whenever app encounters any issue app freezes and black screen appears before crashing

```
public class A extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    final AppContext context = AppContext.getInstance();
    context.setContext(this);
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
            mContext = context.getContext();
            e.getCause().getMessage();
            AppPreference.getInstance().setCrashReason(e.getMessage());
            Intent intent = new Intent ();
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
            startActivity (intent);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    });
}
```

I have searched a lot but all went in vain.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
  public void onCreate ()
  {
    // Setup handler for uncaught exceptions.
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
      @Override
      public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
      {
        handleUncaughtException (thread, e);
      }
    });
  }

public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace(); // not all Android versions will print the stack trace automatically
       
        Intent intent = new Intent ();
        intent.setAction ("com.mydomain.SEND_LOG"); 
        intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // required when starting from Application
        startActivity (intent);
  }
}
```

according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file/19968400#19968400)

Comment: This is what I am doing right now.App gets freeze and black screen turns up.After a while App not responding alert comes up.

Comment: @ashlok malik check provided link for full answer.

Comment: I have already referred the above mentioned link but app is still getting freezed and black screen is displayed as soon as any error is encountered