# Android - crash app without an Uncaught Exception. How can I handle all crashes?

Tags: android, exception, android-logcat

Once in a while my App crashes. Normally I have an default [unCaughtExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file).

I notice that for some versions of Android the app crashes without being in the UncaughtExcpetionHandler.

I also notice that on other Android versions 90% of the crashes the uncaughtexceptions are caught, but 10% not.

How can I make **ALL** crashes report a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library called "Crashlytics"

Crashlytics for Android Studio,gives you instant reports right in your workplace environment.This plugin keeps you informed of the issues within your app so you can track the most prevalent crashes without leaving your IDE.

Here, is the link which will help you to integrate in your app for catching the unknown exceptions without crashing.

https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-crashlytics-for-android-by-fabric-tutorial/

Hope, this Helps !!!

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate this. Does this tool report all possible crashes? And ... does it provide information of a crash 'in the field'? So, not connected to AS?