# How to catch fatal error in my application?

Tags: android, exception

Is it possible to catch globally fatal error in my application?

My application falls to some people and I do not know why ... I need to see the error, why it falls. IDE can catch this error - so maybe I can catch it too + write to my log service.

Thanks.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself some work and add [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/) to your project. This is all you'll ever need.