# Effective Ways to Investigate an Android Crash?

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports

I'm building a game in Unity for iOS and Android, and we're working with an external QA team to test the game. One recurring issue on Android is that a tester will report a crash, and provide an ADB log of the issue, but the log itself contains very little useful data. Sometimes, the only log output corresponding to the crash will be something like "Process x.y.z has died."

So, I started looking into Android Developer documentation and searching around online for the most effective ways to investigate Android crashes. It seems like I should be able to find a crash dump somewhere, or do some instrumentation to provide more helpful information about the crash. I'm basically trying to find clues as to why a crash occurred. But I'm surprisingly finding no documentation or tutorials on the subject!

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this? Is there a documentation page I've missed, or a detailed tutorial on the subject? Is there some file beyond the ADB logs I should request from the tester? Am I lacking some vital app instrumentation that would report crash information in an online dashboard?

Comment: If this build is just your internal build for QA, you can catch any uncaught errors in your Activity and log the stack trace yourself. See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file) - except you don't need to actually send the file, you can just save it to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bugreport` command creates a report that contains device logs, stack traces, and other diagnostic information to help you find and fix bugs in your app. You can capture a bug report from your device using

```
$ adb bugreport
```

You can find more information about this command at [Capture and Read Bug Reports](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report.html)