# Why when we add an android service to an app, delphi automatically include in the dpr of the app the unit of the datamodule of the service?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

When i create a new service, then this service will have a main datamodule (DM), and when i add this service to an already existing app, then delphi automatically add to the dpr (in the uses clauses) of this app the unit of the datamodule:

```
uses ...
     ...
     myService_mainunit;
```

why ? it's also make after not possible to compile under IOS ...

Answer (score 0):

The IDE has absolutely no idea what your intentions are. It has no clue that you only want to use this for Android, regardless of if it's Android-specific code or not. You have to write the code which tells it this, such as using conditionals.

When you created a new Android Service, the IDE set up a pre-made template for you. This template just happens to use a Data Module to do its work. But when you add the Data Module to a project, the IDE simply does not know why you want to add it. It's just doing its job, it does this for *any* and *every* unit you add to your project, regardless of what that unit's purpose is. In fact, there is no such thing as adding a unit to your project and *not* being in the DPR uses.

"it's also make after not possible to compile under IOS"

Again, this is *easily* resolved by wrapping platform conditionals around it. Of course, the IDE "takes control" of the DPR file, so perhaps not *that* easily, as the IDE could malform your code. It is however very possible by *not* including this Data Module in your project, but place it in a location where your project can find it.