# Uncaught error or exception due to Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x90400000 in tid 27887

Tags: android

App is crashing but not showing much info in logcat to solve problem. App just crash and in logcat its just showing :

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x90400000 in tid 27887
```

Its not enough to solve where is exact bug or problem in app. I also searched about Fatal signals but I'm not using any kind of NDK or C++ libs in my project or not doing any hardware related work.

I also  referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19897628/8969251) question but its not working for me. App is just crash and also its showing Fatal signal exception in (dead) option of project means that app is not running after this type of crash!

If you have more doubts about me then see [this  video!](https://youtu.be/DTGciO0JUYM)

Comment: "Its not enough to solve where is exact bug or problem in app" ... how true.

Comment: Because app not giving exception logcat. Its only give like this fatal signal and crash