# How to test unhandled exception?

Tags: java, android, unhandled-exception

I have an Android app for which I would like to save an unhandled exception into the Sqlite DB. I have created all the functionality for saving Error messages into the DB.

My question is, how do I throw unhandled exception?

When I try to do throw new Exception("Save me intodb"), this doesn't work, because I am forced to surround it with try catch.

Any idea how can I actually kill my Android app?

Comment: Take reference from the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file

Comment: For example, an IO Exception?

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos still won't compile until i surround it with try catch

Comment: Runtime exceptions should do; `throw new IllegalStateException();`

Comment: You can just put a try/catch, and then give some values that will cause the exception.

Comment: @JoopEggen this actually worked :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @Joop Eggen in the comments is correct

"Runtime exceptions should do; throw new IllegalStateException();"